# Postfix discard all but transport list

Tags: postfix

I am setting up a backup SMTP server which is located outside of our offices.

The idea is that it should accept all messages addressed to our domains (DNS metric is high, so this should happen only when internal smtp servers are down), and forward them to our internal smtp servers, when they are back up (in reality, it will try to do so every few hours).

I have created a transport map

```
example.com smtp:[ip of smtp server]:25
example2.com smtp:[ip of smtp server]:25
```

and I have set main.cf

```
transport_maps=/etc/postfix/transport
default_transport:discard:Outgoing email disabled on this node
relayhost=
relay_domains =
```

The problem is that, when connecting via telnet, postfix still accepts messages addressed to any domain

When connecting via thunderbird, postfix works properly.

I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of **mynetworks** on main.cf file? If you do the telnet test using a host that is on **mynetworks**, it will be accepted. See http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks

Comment: Apparently, I had a low IQ moment. I was telneting to localhost. Thanks